# Shield encryption partial search

Tags: search, shield

I was wondering as to whether how Shield encryption supports partial search. Any ideas as to what kind of encryption scheme is used by Shield to support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support search if enabled. There's a key that's used when it's enabled to help perform the search. The full details are described in the Salesforce Security Guide under [Behind the Scenes: The Search Index Encryption Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_search_encryption_process.htm).